# BibTeX cannot find .bib file

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I am using TeXworks version 0.4.5 with MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit on Windows 7. When I try to typeset the code

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}
Blah blah \cite{grimm}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{diss}
\end{document}
```

Latex warns that there were undefined references, and in the pdf there is a bolded question mark instead of the reference, and the references section at the end is empty. When I run BibTeX by itself I get the error "I couldn't open the database file diss.bib"

diss.bib looks like this

```
@article{grimm,
  title= "A theorem about random fields"
}
```

Things I have tried which haven't worked:

- Saving the .bib file in the same place as the .tex file
- Savind the file in a TDS-compliant root directory C:\tex-biblio\bibtex\bib\mybiblios\diss.bib and adding this as a root directory in MiKTeX (it accepts it as a new root directory, but BibTeX still can't find the .bib file)
- Creating a BIBINPUTS environmental variable and adding a path to where the .bib file is saved
- Writing a path to the .bib file when defining which bibliography to use:   \bibliography{C:/Users/Sacrebleurgh/Documents/Latex/diss} - i've also tried diss.bib.
- I originally downloaded MiKTeX with LyX so I tried uninstalling them both and then installing MiKTeX by itself, but the problem persisted.

Any suggestion as to what might be wrong or other things to try would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: the bibtex log is

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
The top-level auxiliary file: testdoc.aux
The style file: plain.bst
I couldn't open database file diss.bib
---line 4 of file testdoc.aux
 : \bibdata{diss
 :              }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I found no database files---while reading file testdoc.aux
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "grimm"
(There were 2 error messages)
```

Comment: If I save those files to `dis111.tex` and `diss.bib` and go `pdflatex dis111; bibtex dis111; pdflatex dis111; pdflatex dis111` the citation resolves and `[1]` is listed as `A theorem about random fields` with just a warning from bibtex as it can not sort the database as no author or key field.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried doing it from the command line inside the folder with the .tex and .bib files saved in but bibtex still couldn't find the .bib file.

Comment: can you post the exact bibtex log

Comment: This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
    The top-level auxiliary file: testdoc.aux
    The style file: plain.bst
    I couldn't open database file diss.bib
    ---line 4 of file testdoc.aux
     : \bibdata{diss
     :              }
    I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
    I found no database files---while reading file testdoc.aux
    Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "grimm"
    (There were 2 error messages)

Comment: the aux file should have `\bibdata{diss}` (no space after diss)

Comment: Sorry I didn't get the formatting right, the bibtex log displays it as:
`---line 4 of file testdoc.aux
 : \bibdata{diss
 :              }
`
And in the aux file itself it's just \bibdata{diss} as expected

Comment: Looks like you can't get the formatting in comments, i'll update the main question

Comment: sorry I give up, only thing I can suggest is start by ignoring the files you have and copying the files posted above to new files in a new folder, and see what happens then. Only way I could think of reproducing what you describe is by removing read permission from the .bib file at the Operating system level (has some rogue process died locking the file)

Comment: Did you check if there is some invisible utf8 in the file name or the document?

Answer (score 7):

I finally managed to solve this problem on my own:

Jabref was encoding the bib-files in 16bit and Bibtex was expecting 8bit-code. After switching to 8bit in the Jabref-options the problem solved itself.

Thank you so much for all your efforts.

Comment: as in, UTF-8 and UTF-16?

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error message, with `TexLive` when moving from Windows to Ubuntu, so in case anyone else runs into this...

The file I had been using was called `test.BIB`, which wasn't being recognized by `bibtex`. Copy/pasted the contents to a new file called `test1.bib` and worked fine.

Comment: Unix-derived operating system have filenames that are case-sensitive (unlike Windows). Hence, `test.BIB` and `test.bib` are not the same. BibTeX will look for the file with exension `.bib`, not `.BIB`.